# ReactNative - Unhandled JS Exception: SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native

When Im trying to launch my RN app on iOS 8 I get this weird error: `Unhandled JS Exception: SyntaxError`
And thats all, not any more info more.
Does any1 stumbled across that issue?
On iOs 9+ application runs ok tho.

xCode version: 8.1. Logs from xCode:
`2016-12-07 16:33:57.073 [info][tid:main][RCTBatchedBridge.m:73]     Initializing <RCTBatchedBridge: 0x7fc36c72ae80> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x7fc36c060920>, executor: RCTJSCExecutor)
2016-12-07 16:34:29.369 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript][RCTBatchedBridge.m:509] Failed to execute source code: Unhandled JS Exception: SyntaxError
2016-12-07 16:34:29.369 [fatal][tid:main] Unhandled JS Exception: SyntaxError`

My package.json:
    `{
    "name": "...",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fbjs": "^0.8.6",
    "moment": "^2.16.0",
    "react": "15.3.2",
    "react-native": "^0.37.0",
    "react-native-chart": "^1.0.8-beta",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "0.0.10",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.23.0",
    "react-native-image-progress": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-locale": "0.0.11",
    "react-native-material-kit": "^0.3.3",
    "react-native-message-bar": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-modal-picker": "0.0.16",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.37.0",
    "react-native-timer": "^1.1.2",
    "shortid": "^2.2.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-react-native"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "17.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.0",
    "jest": "17.0.1",
    "jest-react-native": "17.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.3.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "1.0.0"
  }
}`

Node, npm and react-native verisons:
`adamt@Dev-2 ~/D/G/myApp> npm -v
4.0.2
adamt@Dev-2 ~/D/G/myApp> node -v
v4.4.4
adamt@Dev-2 ~/D/G/myApp> react-native -v
react-native-cli: 1.2.0
react-native: 0.37.0`

Any help to why this error occurs would be much welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue React Native version 0.39.

You need to comment out *'use strict';* in line 30 in node_modeles/react-native/Libraries/Core/InitializeCore.js:

```
// 'use strict'; Fix to RN 0.39 - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11389
```

Alternatively, you can go back to React Native version 0.38.