# IOS - React Native - Unhandled JS Exception: SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, react-native

I have facing problem whenever I create a new React Native project. displayed red screen, and got following error message in the xcode console.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Fixed here.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41021827/reactnative-unhandled-js-exception-syntaxerror#answer-41399322

Answer (score 4):

Hi I had the same problem. 
Found the solution  in here : 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11384

TL;DR :
There seems to be a problem with react-native@0.39.0^

So just start the tutorial again and use:
react-native init AwesomeProject --version 0.38.0.

This solved the problem for me.

Have fun

Comment: Fixed on 0.39.2 https://github.com/facebook/react-native/compare/v0.39.1...v0.39.2

Answer (score 2):

It could be that you are using the `**` operator somewhere.  Use `Math.pow` instead.  `**` is not supported when debug js remotely is disabled for some reason.  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11371

Comment: Thanks. This is still an issue with React Native 0.49

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
react-native init AwesomeProject

cd AwesomeProject

react-native run-ios
```