# react native. I install library react native an got error (failed)

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

I create my project by using library Airbnb react-native-map

link:

https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps

and I just run on terminal

```
npm install react-native-maps --save

react-native link

react-native run-ios
```

and run but got an error on terminal like this:

```
The following build commands failed:

    CompileC /Users/preechawanaraksakul/Documents/jobpro/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/AirMaps.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AirMaps.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AIRMapCallout.o AirMaps/AIRMapCallout.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

I use react native version 0.38.0
because I need to use library motion manager
when I upgrade > 0.40 and release on iPhone got error like this:
[IOS - React Native - Unhandled JS Exception: SyntaxError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41074761/ios-react-native-unhandled-js-exception-syntaxerror)

[this is my screenshot from simulator, so it has only box(no display google map)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN3PC.jpg)

and this way can solve my problem to run motion sensor

but

someone tell me upgrade to > 0.40 for use react-native-maps

I need someone help for solve this problem without upgrade > 0.40

thank you for support

Comment: Not sure that your problem can be solved using 0.38. As the dev of RN is really fast, a lot of stuff/bugs are fixed between two patches. I recommend you update to 0.41 and see if you still have your problem.

Comment: I just install version 0.41 and run ios it look okay

next, I just install motion sensor and appear like this:


CompileC /Users/preechawanaraksakul/jobsenior3/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RNMotionManager.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNMotionManager.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Gyroscope.o RNMotionManager/Gyroscope.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

Comment: https://ibb.co/ebLTJv

and this is my screen error when I write code. the code is same "0.38.0" but 0.38.0 don't have an error. in this version have an error. so, I just find solution that someone tell me to downgrade to 0.38.0 and is successful.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/issues/95#issuecomment-232289739) ? With RN 0.41

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as per Airbnb documentation you should not use react-native link command while using react-native-maps.

Please refer to: [this site](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md#important)

If u had already linked kindly follow [this instructions](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md#on-ios)